# Rotating line like a balance board

Tags: objective-c, ios, trigonometry, catransform3d

Well,
i have a circle like this in the photo.
I want to rotate my red line to the degree that i want.

The circle start from 0 to 300 degrees.

I started to do something with

```
CGFloat wAngle = Degrees2Radians([_Weight.text intValue]/300.0*360);
_Arrow.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (wAngle + M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
```

but in this snippet, 0 value was on top, not on bottom.
Probably because i'm not a genius in trigonometry... :)

[image]

What is the correct way to rotate properly the arrow?
How are the values of angle to set?

thanks.

Comment: What's the initial frame of the arrow layer?

Comment: @Moxy is in the center of screen because i don't have a particular  layout. The frame is indifferent for me. Why you ask me this?

Comment: I didn't express myself well, I wanted to know the initial "direction" of the arrow (the degree - from 0 to 300 - it's pointing to). It's important for the transform to be correct otherwise there will be a phase. But I assume it points to 0  (M_PI*3/2)

Comment: I want the arrow pointing to the bottom. Desiderata degree = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to transform degrees and radians. You have a relative value:

```
CGFloat relativeAngle = [_Weight.text intValue] / 300.0;
```

So just use it:

```
_Arrow.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(relativeAngle * M_PI*2, 0, 0, 1);
```

If the start is wrong just change the initial position of your view.
(Or sum up the wrong angle to the new angle. Like `(relativeAngle * M_Pi*2 + correction)`.

```
// what PI means in degrees
M_PI * 2 = 360°  
M_PI     = 180°  
M_PI_2   = 90°  
M_PI_4   = 45°
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your relative angle like this

```
// transform your degrees (0->300) to radians
// (considering your starting direction is at M_PI*3/2)
CGFloat relativeAngle = - [_Weight.text intValue] * M_PI / 150.0;

_Arrow.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(relativeAngle, 0, 0, 1);
```